# Transpose data from wide format to long format excel

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, my excel sheet is composed of data that are not in long format.
[image]

I want to cut the data to paste at the bottom of the first 2 columns to get something like this:

[image]

I have written some vba code to allow me to do the cutting and pasting. However, the code doesn't seem to exit the Find Loop and continuously finds and cuts. I want to stop finding after all columns after the 1st 2 are cut and pasted to the bottom. What edits can I make to the code to allow the find to escape the loop? Thank you

```
Sub FindTextInSheets()
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim myColor As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Corp As Range
    Dim rowscount As Variant
    Dim rowsno As Integer
                Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Code", _
                                After:=Range("B1"), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = rng.Address
                    Do
                        rng.Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 1)).Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Selection.Cut
                        Range("A1").Select
                        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.FindNext(rng)
                    Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> FirstAddress
                End If
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: Since you are searching in all cells in the sheet (thats what `Activesheet.cells` is) you will keep finding the same cell, but in a differenct location to what you stored in `FirstAddress` - hence the infinite loop.

Comment: How can I edit my code to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using VBA, you can do split and append in Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365).

I assumed your actual data had more `Types` then just `AA`.

*Note that in the sample data table, the column headers will have all different names.  This happens automatically when you create a Excel table, whether you do that manually, or when Power Query does it for you when initially selecting a cell in the source data range.*

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

The algorithm consists of splitting the table into pairs of columns, then appending them into a single table.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],

//Select column pairs for new tables
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    colNamePairs = List.Generate(
        ()=>[pair={colNames{0},colNames{1}}, idx = 0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(colNames),
        each [pair={colNames{[idx]+2}, colNames{[idx]+3}}, idx = [idx]+2],
        each [pair]            
    ),
    tblPairs = List.Generate(
            ()=> [tbl=Table.SelectColumns(Source,colNamePairs{0}),idx = 0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(colNamePairs),
            each [tbl=Table.SelectColumns(Source,colNamePairs{[idx]+1}), idx=[idx]+1],
            each Table.RenameColumns([tbl],List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames([tbl]), colNamePairs{0}}))),
    
    combine = Table.Combine(tblPairs),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(combine,{{"Type", Order.Ascending}})

in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

**Original**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define your worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'or use ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    ' find the first repeating column to know how many columns will there be in the end
    Dim FoundAt As Range
    Set FoundAt = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=ws.Cells(1, 1), _
                                  After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                  MatchCase:=False)
                                  
    ' check if something was found
    If FoundAt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No repeating columns found.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim AmountOfColumns As Long  ' amount of columns in the end
    AmountOfColumns = FoundAt.Column - 1
    
    Dim LastColumn As Long  ' last used column
    LastColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' check if repeting columns sum up
    If LastColumn Mod AmountOfColumns <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Amount of columns is not a multiple of the first repeating column"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' next free row in column A where we want to paste data
    Dim NextFreeRow As Long
    NextFreeRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    
    ' loop through columns (block wise)
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 + AmountOfColumns To LastColumn Step AmountOfColumns
        Dim LastRow As Long  ' last used row in that column
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' copy data
        ws.Cells(NextFreeRow, 1).Resize(LastRow - 1, AmountOfColumns).Value = ws.Cells(2, iCol).Resize(LastRow - 1, AmountOfColumns).Value
        
        ' calculate next free row in column A
        NextFreeRow = NextFreeRow + LastRow - 1
    Next iCol
    
    ' delete all the copied data columns
    ws.Columns(AmountOfColumns + 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=LastColumn - AmountOfColumns).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
End Sub
```

You start with

[image]

and end up with

[image]

Comment: I tried this by the line "If LastColumn Mod AmountOfColumns <> 0 Then", is giving me a "Run time error '11': Division by zero"

Comment: @lan that means that the word `Code` of the first cell was not found anywhere in the first row. Make sure the headers repeat like in the shown example.